# Is this statement accurate: We are 4D beings (l,w,d,t) with the ability to visualize in 3D (using our brain) and see in 2D (using our retinas)?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, biology, perception, visualization

I've read conflicting information on us being 4D beings (length, width, depth, time) and in what dimension we are able to see. Interested to hear your thoughts, especially if you provide sources.

Comment: One should not mistake the geometry of causality (+++- metric) for the dimensionality of the world. The world is three dimensional. There are only three different linearly independent directions in which we can move. One can not move in time, only one theory pretends that one can to simplify the description of the world.

Comment: @FlatterMann are we then 3D beings (l,w,d) with the ability to visualize in 3D (using our brain) and see in 2D (using our retinas)?

Comment: I see just fine in 3D, because I've got binocular vision.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything for something to really *be* a 4-dimensional object.  Processes, even extremely short processes, are infinitely too big to fit in moments, and when we say that something *is* something, we infer that that's what it is *right now*. You can represent the *idea* of process as a 4-dimensional object, and then describe things about the 4-dimensional object, which you can use to make predictions about what you will measure in the future given some past measurements of the process. It's useful to discuss 4-dimensional objects using the same language we use for 3-dimensional objects (consider discussing a movie or a song), including pretending that they exist in the present moment, even though that's logically impossible, but it's just a linguistic convenience.

Comment: Got it, so when we refer to an object it only makes sense to refer to what it is in a single moment of time. Would it be fair to say we are 3 dimensional beings having a 4 dimensional experience?

Answer (score 0):

You’re basically right. Our bodies are physical objects that exist in 3d space and pass (in one direction we think) through time so you could say we are 4d beings.

Our retinas are 2d optical detectors which act as part of our eyeballs, so we see in 2 spatial dimensions.

But using our brains we can (1) infer 3d spatial structures from what we see using our 2 eyes (this is done using parallax of our 2 eyes but also using our neural networks to infer 3d structure based on our historical sensory input) and (2) record what we see over time so that we can visualize spatially 3d objects moving/changing in time. So if you say we are 4d beings then I would say we can also visualize/perceive in 4d.